# Go test compiles successfully, but go build doesn't

Tags: windows, go, testing, compilation

I am trying to test a main package in go (in Windows) and the test seems to be cached, although I delete completely the cache (`go clean -cache`).

To test this I changed a file (`parseinput.go`), so that it produces an error during compilation (undefined variable). The result is, that main package cannot be built:

```
go\src\xxx\apimonitor> go build
# xxx/apimonitor
.\inputparser.go:15:2: undefined: err
.\inputparser.go:16:19: undefined: err
```

,but tests still complete successfully (`go test` or even `go test -a`):

```
go\src\xxx\apimonitor> go test
PASS
ok      xxx/apimonitor  0.786s
```

Any clues as to why this keeps happening and why test does not recompile? Any other place where this package might be cached from previous builds?

---

**Update**

After adding some print statements, it seems that test (`go test`) compiles **successfully** `inputparser.go` (despite that `err` variable is undefined), but build fails (as depicted above). That's what led me to believe that test was cached. Here is a sample of the source that fails in build:

```golang
func parseStoreInput(strArray []string) (inputStoreTransactionHash, error) {
    var parsedIn inputStoreTransactionHash
    if !validateInput(strArray, 1, true) {
        return parsedIn, errors.New("Expecting an escaped JSON string as input")
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(strArray[0]), &parsedIn)
    return parsedIn, err
}
```

Any clues/documentation as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Hard to say without the actual code...

Comment: Does your test import the apimonitor package? `go test -count 1` is the canonical way to re-run cached tests.

Comment: @icio apimonitor is my main package.